# Show data in meteor-template from array in

Tags: meteor

I have restaurants in a MongoDB with this structure

```
"_id" : "R68ZkDqdfj7Qsc9Kx",
"clubname" : "Italiano",
"description" : "Best italian food in town.",
"capacity" : "100",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-04-13T16:20:20.683Z"),
"visitors" : [
    {
        "persons" : 0
    }
],
"createdBy" : "mFWrAd3SdyP4dRgEW"
```

I have no problems retrieving the name, description, capacity... data, but I can't figure out how to read the value 0 in the array under visitors.

In MongoDB I can do:

```
db.clubs.findOne({_id: "R68ZkDqdfj7Qsc9Kx"}).visitors[0].persons
```

But how do I do something similar in the Meteor template?

```
{{visitors}} returns [object Object]
```

I have also tried

```
{{#with visitors}}
```

Comment: `visitors` is an array. Are you trying to iterate over it and show `persons` in, for example, a list? In other words, if `visitors` had 10 elements, what do you want rendered to your template?

Comment: Yes. And I don´t know how to handle the array.

Now there is only persons but I will be able to change this and for instance have 'children', and 'adults' instead of just persons. And in that case I want to iterate over the array and display:

Children: 5
Adults: 10

Comment: Thanks. Thought I tried that :-) That displays the valu 0. But I also want to display the label. Persons: 0

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`visitors` is an array, so you you'll probably want to iterate over it and show your data in a list. Here's an example:

```html
<ul>
  {{#each visitors}}
    <li>Persons: {{persons}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```